# Мониторинг сервера кс

Tags: php, сервер, библиотеки

Появилась нужда мониторить сервер кс.

Есть ли какие-то библиотеки, в которых это реализовано достаточно просто?

Comment: Купи скрипт...

Comment: Хотите сказать что, вы ничего не нашли по запросу "скрипт мониторинга серверов cs php"?

Comment: Подскажите, сервера может мониторить только владелец, кто угодно, или кто-угодно за денежку?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот самый простой пример мониторинга CS 1.6, который выводит:

Сервер: 46.38.56.3:27015

Название: Army Ranks 1.3

Карта: cs_assault

Игроков: 19/24

Статус: On-line

```
<?php

$server = '46.38.56.3';
$port   = '27015';

function GetServerInfo($server,$port) { 
     $fp = @fsockopen("udp://".$server, $port); 
     if (!$fp) return false;

     @fwrite($fp,"\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\x54\x53\x6F\x75\x72\x63\x65\x20\x45\x6E\x67\x69\x6E\x65\x20\x51\x75\x65\x72\x79\x00".chr(10)); 
     $start=time(); 
     socket_set_timeout($fp,1); 
     $st=fread($fp,1); 
     $r=socket_get_status($fp); 
     $result['status'] = $r["timed_out"];
     $r=$r["unread_bytes"]; 
     if ($r == 0) { @fclose($fp); return false;} 
     $st.=fread($fp,$r); 
     @fclose($fp);

     $st=substr($st,5); 
     $address=SubStr($st,0,StrPos($st,chr(0))); 
     $address=str_replace(chr(0),"|",$address); 
     $st=SubStr($st,StrPos($st,chr(0))+1); 
     $name=SubStr($st,0,StrPos($st,chr(0))); 
     $st=SubStr($st,StrPos($st,chr(0))+1); 
     $map=SubStr($st,0,StrPos($st,chr(0))); 
     $st=SubStr($st,StrPos($st,chr(0))+1); 
     $st=SubStr($st,StrPos($st,chr(0))+1); 
     $st=SubStr($st,StrPos($st,chr(0))+1); 
     $current=ord(SubStr($st,0,1)); 
     $max=ord(SubStr($st,1,1));

     if ($map == "") return false; 
     $result['map'] = $map; 
     $result['name']= $name; 
     $result['current'] = $current; 
     $result['max'] = $max;

     return $result; 
}

$serv = GetServerInfo($server,$port);

if ($serv) {
echo '
Сервер: '.$server.':'.$port.'
<br>
Название: '.$serv['name'].'
<br>
Карта: '.$serv['map'].'
<br>
Игроков: '.$serv['current'].'/'.$serv['max'].'
<br>
Статус: On-line
';
} else {
echo 'Статус: Off-line';
}

?>
```